# ViewWillAppear not working on ScrollView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

please help. I have been searching for the solution to this question but no luck. I have a horizontal scrollview that has two pages as subviews and I can horizontally scroll between them. Not, I want to trigger an event that will tell me when one of them (the two pages) is show. I have successfully added viewWillAppear to ScrollView but when I add it to the subviews, the method is not triggered. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` property when `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called on the delegate (You'll have to assign a `UIScrollViewDelegate`). `viewDidAppear` is designed to be called on `UIViewControllers` under very specific conditions.

Comment: Thank You @Stavash . I have taken the contentOffset and checked if it is 0.0 or 320.0 to check which page is it in the scrollViewDidScroll and when the contentOffset reaches that number, i can do whatever. Once again, thank you.